# ErrorDocument doesn't display page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess file unfortunately I doesn't redirect to the error page when it encounters a 404 response code

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index.html index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?params=$1$2$3 [NC]
```

Here is my PHP code witch returns 404:

```
if ($param1 != 'en')
    {
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        die();
    }
```

I must mention that I don't have access to the apache logs so I can't figure it what is happening. And the browser receives succesefully the 404 error message, only it displays a blank page.

Comment: Of course it doesn’t, because you redirect “everything” that is not a physical file or folder to your index.php – so the defined error document does not come into play at all. So you will have output the desired error message from within your script as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing strange going on here. Apache uses the `ErrorDocument` directive *only*, when it can't find a document itself. But apparently, it has found your PHP script, which it calls. What HTTP status is set by PHP is of no further concerns to Apache (apart from delivering it to the client).

If you want your custom error document, include it before the `die()`:

```
include_once "404.php";
die();
```